# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit' extract numbers from data that is found

Tags: python

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

This is a persistent error I keep receiving, I am searching for data and it gets the people name, form and score, I am trying to get the scores into an average,

```
pls enter a fullname >> Geoffrey Chiasson
Geoffrey Chiasson   F   6   1   3
```

I'm trying to get the 6 1 and 3 out of it.

Here is my code:

```
def searchQuerySurname(alist):
    searchQuery = [ ]
    nofound = 0 ## no found set at 0
    surname = input("pls enter a fullname >> ") ## asks user for surname
    surname = surname.lower() ## converts to lower case
    for row in alist:
        if row[0].lower() == surname: ## surname appears in row0
              searchQuery.append(row) ## appends results
              numbers =int(filter(searchQuery.isdigit, str1))
              nofound = nofound + 1 ## increments variable
    if nofound == 0:
        print("there were no matches") 
    return searchQuery
```

I get this as it crashes:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `searchQuery.isdigit` in the first place? It looks like you copied some code without understanding what it does.

Comment: Even if you used the right method reference there, you cannot use `int()` on the `filter()` object anyway.

Comment: its some old code im trying to edit

Comment: could you edit it to work, what is the name of the variable with the data in.

Comment: @Rasnaamt: what should the code do? Your `numbers` variable is assigned, but never used. There's also `str1`, which is used but never assigned. Probably you should just remove the line altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You try to apply string method `isdigit` to a list:

```
>>> 'abc'.isdigit()
False
>>> '123'.isdigit()
True
>>> [].isdigit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

You should apply checking `isdigit` not to list `searchQuery`, but to the each element (`string)` of the list.

Comment: I need clarification. What is the input and output data? What manipulations should be performed with the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
map(int, filter(str.isdigit, searchQuery))
```

This first filters `searchQuery`, using `str.isdigit`, then applies `int` to every remaining result.